# Is there a way in Perl to get the coordinates of a Path from a PDF in the same coordinate system as the PDF text?

Tags: perl, pdf, coordinates

I have a PDF page that contains both paths and text. I need to find the coordinates of both the paths and the text in the same coordinate system. I can use [CAM::PDF](https://metacpan.org/pod/CAM::PDF) to get the Text coordinates as per below:

```
use CAM::PDF;
use PDF::ToText;
#open pdf file and look at pg1
my $pdf = CAM::PDF->new($pdfFileName);
my $contentTree = $pdf->getPageContentTree(1);
$contentTree->render("PDF::ToText");
```

I can't work out how to get the coordinates of the paths on the same PDF page. I can look at the PDF page contents and see the path coordinates but I think these need to be translated using the current transformation matrix, as I know that some specific text characters sit on the same location on the page as the path (like x marks the spot on a treasure map...) but there is no overlap in the coordinates that I can get (text and path are out by ~500 units). Is there a way to get the path coordinates using CAM::PDF (or some other some other Perl module?) in the same coordinate system (device space?) as the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of CAM::PDF. Indeed, you're on the right track. Take a look at the implementation of `CAM::PDF::Renderer::Dump`, which is very simple. That class demonstrates how to capture the coordinates of a text command. Next, look at `CAM::PDF::GS::NoText` and see what other methods you can override in your own custom render class similar to `CAM::PDF::Renderer::Dump`.

Comment: Thanks Chris, needed that push in the right direction. I created my own renderer and have overridden some functions from CAM::PDF::GS::NoText and am now getting the coordinates I need.